# SwiftUI Sheet modal dismiss gets triggered when resizing the app window with a Scroll / Grid view

Tags: macos, swiftui

I have a macOS app with a collection of words in a ScrollView that presents a modal when a word is clicked on. When I click on one of the top words, the modal shows, and I can resize the window while the modal stays intact.

I then hit Esc key to dismiss the modal, scroll down a whole bunch of words, and when I click on another word, the modal displays fine. However, when I try to resize the window this time, the modal keeps dismissing and re-appearing. The sample code below prints "onDismiss" to the console as you resize the window.

What is triggering the modal to dismiss itself and re-appear and why does it happen only for words mid-way down the scroll view?

As you can see, the 'apple' modal stays the same, whereas the 'passionfruit' modal dismisses and re-appears (you can see it flashing) as I resize the window:
[image: screen capture of issue]

Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SheetIssueView: View {
    let collection: [String] = [
        "apple", "banana", "orange", "grape", "pear", "mango", "cherry", "kiwi", "watermelon", "pineapple",
        "strawberry", "blueberry", "raspberry", "blackberry", "apricot", "peach", "plum", "lemon", "lime", "coconut",
        "pomegranate", "melon", "dragonfruit", "guava", "papaya", "fig", "kiwifruit", "passionfruit", "avocado", "date",
        "grapefruit", "cantaloupe", "honeydew", "mangosteen", "durian", "breadfruit", "ackee", "starfruit", "quince",
        "lychee", "gooseberry", "elderberry", "mulberry", "boysenberry", "cranberry", "lingonberry", "loganberry",
        "persimmon", "tamarind", "kiwano", "cucumber", "tomato", "bell pepper", "zucchini", "eggplant", "pumpkin",
        "squash", "butternut", "acorn", "carrot", "beet", "radish", "turnip", "sweet potato", "potato", "yam", "onion",
        "garlic", "ginger", "celery", "cabbage", "lettuce", "spinach", "kale", "broccoli", "cauliflower", "asparagus",
        "brussels sprouts", "corn", "peas", "green beans", "artichoke", "leek", "shallot", "okra", "bamboo shoots",
        "water chestnuts", "bean sprouts", "jicama", "cassava", "lotus root", "rhubarb", "cactus", "fennel", "salsify",
        "plantain", "yucca", "cattail", "lotus seed", "watercress", "sorrel", "dandelion greens", "parsnip", "sweet corn",
        "gourds", "water caltrop", "chayote", "taro", "burdock root", "arrowhead", "sunchokes"
    ]
    
    private class WordManager: ObservableObject {
        @Published var selectedWord: String?
    }
    
    @StateObject private var wordManager = WordManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 300, maximum: 300), spacing: 0)]) {
                ForEach(collection, id: \.id) { word in
                    Text(word)
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            self.wordManager.selectedWord = word
                        }
                        .sheet(item: $wordManager.selectedWord,
                            onDismiss: {
                                print("onDismiss")
                            },
                            content: { word in
                                WordDetailView(word: word)
                                    .frame(width: 500, height: 500)
                            })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct WordDetailView: View {
    var word: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(word)
    }
}

extension String: Identifiable {
    public var id: String { return self }
}
```

Environment:
Xcode 14.3.1, macOS 13.4.1

Comment: You're lying to the compiler and telling it that each word has a constantly changing `id` -- every time the View gets re-evaluated, the id changes. Use truly `Identifiable` data and you'll be fine.

Comment: I assume you were referring to the `Identifiable` conformance using `UUID().uuidstring` -- so I changed it to return `self` and also changed the identifier in the ForEach to `id: \.id`, which should truly be unique and constant at least within the context of this code I provided. Though even with the changes, the issue still exists. But you seem to be onto something else that I may not be understanding. Can you elaborate more on "View gets re-evaluated"?

Comment: I added a screen recording to show the issue.

Comment: What happens if you move the `sheet` outside of the `LazyVGrid`? I assume that the elements are appearing/disappearing as the window size changes, so the sheet doesn't exist any more.

Comment: Yep, putting the `sheet` on the `ScrollView` fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sheet` modifier should go outside of the `LazyVStack`. Right now, the element with the `sheet` attached may disappear as the view size changes (because of the behavior of the `Lazy` stack, which only shows visible views [plus a small buffer]), which will make the `sheet` close.

```
ScrollView {
  LazyVStack {

  } // <-- Here
} // <-- Or here
```